# How to get readable name of List in SP 2010 using REST API

Tags: 2010, list

`/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/` gives collection of ugly names. I have found some articles about the way SP creates those ones. But are there any rules to make inverse thing - from internal list name e.g. "MyList" get user-friendly name "My List" which is visible on Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real way to do so using the SharePoint 2010 REST API, because `ListData.svc` only retrieves list **item** data; no data about the actual lists themselves.

You can get what you're looking for by using the SharePoint Javascript Object Model (JSOM) though:

```
var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var myLists = myCtx.get_web().get_lists();
myCtx.load(myLists);
myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var arrListTitle = []
    for (var i = 0; i < myLists.get_count(); i++) {
        arrListTitle.push(myLists.getItemAtIndex(i).get_title());
    }
    console.log(arrListTitle);
}, function(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message())
});
```

This will give you an array of all of the 'friendly' list titles as they are defined in the UI and as demonstrated logs them to your browser dev tools console, but you could easily start with this and modify the behavior.

Post the entire snippet into your browser dev tools on one of your SP pages and you can see the output array value.

Comment: That is good but I develop native C++ application

Comment: That would have been useful to include in your original question :) If you were using C# there is a Client Object Model that could assist, but for C++ you'll have to go the SOAP web services route, and I'm not fluent enough with them to provide you anything useful unfortunately.

Comment: well, thank you anyway - it's good to know how to do this, but knowing what cannot be done is also valuable